# Problem with showing excepted output in my text game

Tags: python, output

I am on the good way to finish my text game. All works good, but I saw in my result quite strange thing. When player answer in two last sentences and before program counted points achieved by player in my text game, I saw, that program shows two answers which player write in sentence and then show total score achieved by player after a whole game.

Here, you can see my code and give me a solution below in the comments.

http://wklejto.pl/732167

Comment: Umm... unless your code is *the* hyperlink itself, please paste a [mcve] of the code [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55677832/edit). (Also, welcome to StackOverflow!)

Comment: Please review [ask] and update this question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the input to the second and third sentences. You could avoid this by doing it this way:

```
def game():
    score = 0
    first_sentence = "Ala ma kota, a kot ma ... (Ale, tomka, ogon, downa):  "
    second_sentence = "Tylko biedronka, nie ma ... (kropek, skrzydel, ogonka):  "
    third_sentence = "Bez pracy nie ma ... (kolaczy, efektow, pieniedzy):  "
    good_answers = ['Ale', 'ogonka', 'kolaczy']
    if input(first_sentence) == good_answers[0]:
        second_answer = input(second_sentence)
        score += 1
    else:
        second_answer = input(second_sentence)

    if second_answer == good_answers[1]:
        third_answer = input(third_sentence)
        score += 1
    else:
        third_answer = input(third_sentence)

    if third_answer == good_answers[2]:
        print('Your score is:', score)
        score += 1
        backToGame()
    else:
        print('End of game.')
        print('Your score is:', score)
        backToGame()
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions". Right now, if the OP's link dies, your answer will no longer be of use to anyone; whereas the goal for which SO was founded was to build a long-lived database of canonical questions and answers. Thus, it's better to encourage folks to improve their questions to be complete and self-contained before answering (or edit the question yourself to improve it, if you're so inclined!) so your answer is useful not just to the OP right now, but for *everyone* indefinitely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, I'll keep that in mind! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I find my solution that i don't need to create one more variable "second_answer" or "third_answer". I moved second_sentence and third sentence to if instruction like this: https://repl.it/repls/RectangularColorfulWifi